# Stream video to WebRTC from app not browser

Tags: java, python, stream, webrtc

I have search high and low and have yet to find a “clear” answer to if this can be done or how to do it (I’m happy to write a app just need to know what to use)

1. I have a Raspberry Pi, I want to stream video and audio from its USB Web cam to a WebRTC-Server/Client.
2. My Raspberry Pi has no GUI/Xwindows installed and thus has no web browser (even with a GUI there is no WebRTC browser that works on Raspberry Pi)

So what I want is a way to make an app in Java or Python or JS that needs no GUI… I give it start commands to tell it where the WebRTC server is (IP) and the room to join… or I set them in a config file..
-   It could be I need to tell the app/code what video and audio to send as well.

? So what code is out there that would enable me to develop the above solution?

I have seen a few things but I’m not clear if they can be used to so what I’m asking :

- Janus (Not sure if it’s made for doing what I want) http://janus.conf.meetecho.com/
- Gstreamer (This may be it but again not sure how I would sent too my RTCserver)
- Sourcey (close but in C++ and it looked to have problems in using outside WebRTC server
  http://sourcey.com/webrtc-native-to-browser-video-streaming-example/

Again to explain:

1. I have small Linux device (RasPi) it has web cam and microphone
2. It has no GUI No xWindows and so no Browser to do WebRTC on
3. I want to stream the webcam video and audio to my WebRTC-Server/Client
4. I don’t need to get video back from the other client.. This is out only.
5. I am not trying to turn my RasPi into a WebRTC Server, have seen that a lot but it’s not what I’m asking for.

I know Java and Python I’m happy to develop the app in one of them I just need to know what technology to use to send video/audio to a WebRTC server and any supporting info with in is helpful.
I will post link to working app here once it’s developed, may be useful to others that want to stream to a WebRTC room from small cheap Linux device.

Answer (score 2):

[UV4L](http://linux-projects.org) exactly does what you want:

> Thanks to a new, special module for UV4L, it is now possible to join a
>   room of any Jitsi Meet Web Conference anywhere (including those on the
>   free, public meet.jit.si service) and **broadcast live video and audio
>   from your camera and microphone to all the participants or viewers in
>   the room without the need of any browser!**

In your application it's enough to send the proper commands to the UV4L Streaming Server via HTTP/GET to start&stop the streaming and pass the URL of the Jitsi videobridge you want to connect to.

Comment: What if you don't want the heavy Jitsi video bridge in there?  I want to point a browser to the RaspberryPi and go direct.